# Can you change the styling on resizable html elements?

Tags: html, css, resize

I have a chat box that is resizable. It has

```
resize:both;overflow:auto
```

in the CSS. So at the bottom right of the div, there is a little arrow thing that you can click on and resize the div.

Is there another way to style this? I'd much rather be able to put the mouse on any corner of the div and resize it, or at least have that arrow be on the top right or top left of the div. I'd also like to be able to change what the arrow looks like, to make it more obvious what it does.

Also, is it possible to have the cursor change when the mouse is over the arrow?

Comment: It is not possible, it is browser dependent. Better look for alternatives, as auto-resize: http://amaury.carrade.eu/projects/jquery/autoResize.html, or jQuery-ui resize: http://jqueryui.com/resizable/

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: this is not possible.

However using javascript and CSS a custom solution can be made. You can place a little div in a corner using absolute positioning. Then have javascript resize the textbox on dragging the little div.